# How to unit-test IBOutlet connections?

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, interface-builder

I've been trying to verify in my tests (GTM) that when a nib file is loaded, its IBOutlets were properly connected in InterfaceBuilder.

However I keep getting nil references, despite calling [myViewController viewDidLoad] before asserting that the reference should exist.

Are there any gotchas here, or should this be mocked somehow ?

cheers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

calling `[myViewContoller viewDidLoad]` does not load the view. You want `[myViewController loadView]`, which loads up the .nib and the references.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, accepted this answer for the sake of brievity.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be calling -viewDidLoad.

If by "when a nib file is loaded", you mean you're calling -initWithNibName:bundle:, that does *not* load the nib. That just sets the nib name that is used to load the view. The "correct" way to load the view is to call -[UIViewController view] (which calls loadView if it was not already loaded, which by default loads from the nib, which has a default name of [[self class] description] or so, I think).  -[UIViewController view] will call viewDidLoad for you.